# reactjs formatting issue + keypress event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have three questions:

1. There is apparently an unrecognized token in my `_dismiss` function. What am I doing wrong? Chrome points to the line `progress.currentStep: 4,` specifically a couple of spaces before `progress.currentStep:4,`. Any ideas why?
2. I'm trying to trigger a state change when the `esc` key is pressed. I want to change the state so the returned things are changed. In the return statement there are a bunch of if/else statements, displaying different elements depending on if the `currentStep == 1` or 2, or 3. FYI `4 == numSteps`, so I want nothing to render after the escape key has been pressed. Is this the proper way to do it? The listener is added when the component has rendered, then removed when component is unmounted. My only concern is changing the state would make the component fresh and call `reconcileState`, which leads to my last question ---
3. When is `reconcileState` called? The react docs on reconciliation wasn't very clear, and most docs on the lifecycle of components focused on mounting and un-mounting.

   ```
   import xContainerStore ... etc.
   class xContainer extends Container {
   constructor(props) {
           super(props);
           this._dismiss = this._dismiss.bind(this);
   }

   componentDidMount() {
           super.componentDidMount();
           document.addEventListener("keydown", this._dismiss, false);
   }

   componentWillUnmount() {
           super.componentWillUnmount();
           document.removeEventListener("keydown", this._dissmiss, false);
   }

   reconcileState(state, props) {
           Object.assign(state, props);
           state.progress = xContainerStore.progress;
           state.currentUser = xContainerStore.currentUser;
   }

   _dismiss(event) {
           if (event.keyCode == 27) {
                   this.setState({
                           progress.currentStep: 4, // when you press esc, state is changed and some modal now should not show up.
                   });
           }
           console.log("esc pressed");
   }

   stores() { return [OnboardingStore]; }

   render() {
           if (this.state.progress.currentStep >= this.state.progress.numSteps) return null;

           return (
                   some stuff depending on state
               ...
          )
   ```

   }

Answer (score 0):

1. Extra comma
2. Yes.
3. reconcileState? I have never seen that function before. Is that in the React documentation? what are you trying to accomplish there?

Comment: I took out the comma and it still gives me an unexpected token parsing error. Any other ideas?

Comment: Oh yes. I didn't see it at first. The key from an object can't contain dots. So you might want to rename it. Or if what you want is to set currentStep inside progress, it should be `this.setState({ progress: { currentProgress: 4 } })`